# How to get all videos from device storage in Android App

Tags: java, android

I want to display all the videos present in the phone storage (internal or SD card) inside my app's listview and my old code is giving exceptions on new 7.0 devices. My targetSDK API level is 23. I also get a warning in the IDE that "managedQuery" method is deprecated. The method that I have in my project is:

```
private boolean getVideoList() {
    Cursor var1 = this.managedQuery(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_data", "_id", "_display_name", "duration"}, (String)null, (String[])null, " _id DESC");
    int var2 = var1.getCount();
    if(var2 <= 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        var1.moveToFirst();

        for(int var4 = 0; var4 < var2; ++var4) {
            Uri var5 = Uri.withAppendedPath(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ContentUtill.getLong(var1));
            String var6 = var1.getString(var1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_display_name"));
            String var7 = var1.getString(var1.getColumnIndex("_data"));
            String var8 = ContentUtill.getTime(var1, "duration");
            VideoData var9 = new VideoData(var6, var5, var7, var8);
            this.videoList.add(var9);
            var1.moveToNext();
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The exception is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1693)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:183)
  at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel (DatabaseUtils.java:135)
  at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query (ContentProviderNative.java:421)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:536)
  at android.content.ContentResolver.query (ContentResolver.java:478)
  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery (Activity.java:2368)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity.getVideoList (SelectVideoActivity.java:61)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity.access$0 (SelectVideoActivity.java:60)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity$loadVideo.doInBackground (SelectVideoActivity.java:170)
  at video.format.converter.view.SelectVideoActivity$loadVideo.doInBackground (SelectVideoActivity.java:1)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:304)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

I do have the new permission model implemented in my project and I do ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions but still the exception. Any good way to get a list of videos and populate my POJO class with properties:

```
   public String Duration;
   public Uri VideoUri;
   public long videoId;
   public String videoName;
   public String videoPath;
```

Comment: Have you specified permission in manifest? i.e runtime permissions ?

Comment: yes that is in place, I have permissions in manifest as well in my java code (request permission with new permission model)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with Android Marshmallow or above. You need to get runtime permission for READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.Just putting it in manifest will not work for Android 6+. Here is a link to add runtime permission.[Link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Also managed query is deprecated, query like this:

```
 Cursor var1 = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{"_data", "_id", "_display_name", "duration"}, (String)null, (String[])null, " _id DESC");
```

Comment: When I say new runtime permission model, I meant that code base request to user to allow read/write storage. So that prompt for Allow/Deny is getting displayed to user. ok I will change my managedquery code but are you sure that your code is latest and free of securityexception. is it tested?

Comment: ok then it will go into my live app. Hoping that I won't see anymore crash reports for this securityexception

Answer (score 0):

```
    void findVideos(File dir, ArrayList<String> list){
        for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory())
                    findVideos(file, list);
            else if(file.getAbsolutePath().contains(".mp4")) 
                   list.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

Comment: how to get videouri, duration of video from File object?